# Javascript file upload e.target == null when choosing another file after initially chose one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I've currently implemented the file uploading using `<input>` and for some reason when I try to change the file after already chosen the file. The website will crash stating the even.target is null.

```tsx
<Button label="Upload S3 File">
  <input type="file" onInput={(e) => handleFileUpload(e)} />
</Button>
```

And here's my handler function, to be exact, the error happens on

`file: e.target.files ? e.target.files[0] : null,`

```tsx
// Set up the handler
const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState<RequestData>({
  overrideUbi: "",
  marketplace: "",
  isTier1: "",
  brandName: "",
  brandURL: "",
  file: null
});

const handleFormChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  // console.log(event);
  setFormValues((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    [name]: value,
  }));
};

const handleFileUpload = (e: any) => {
  console.log("upload");
  console.log(e.target)
  console.log(e.target.files)
  if (!e.target.files) return;
  setFormValues((prevFormValues) => ({
    ...prevFormValues,
    file: e.target.files ? e.target.files[0] : null,
  }));
};
```

Not sure why it states e.target is null if I choose another file after have one file chosen already. My if statement for checking e.target == null also doesn't work preventing the website from crashing.
Thanks!

Update:
I've attached a couple of screenshot showing the exact error.

[image: Warning Messages]

[image: e.target is null]

One interesting finding is that if I use e.persist(), I can change the file I want to upload without triggering this error. I don't know why exactly that is, if someone can explain what is going on in this lifecycle I would truly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide the exact error message as well as the console.log results.

Comment: @Ben Got it. I'm updating it now.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `onInput` instead of `onChange`?

Comment: Yes. The thing is this input field for some reason doesn't work wiht onChange. It won't call the handler with onChange, the only thing it works with is onInput.

Answer (score 0):

try `e.currentTarget.files`, if you have a reference set on the input component.